"Session ID unknown" in socket.io: Tried Cookies, WebSocket - Still no success
My socket app is running in DO managed k8s cluster, im getting "Session ID unknown" error on my frontend

socket app replica count: 2

I think, I have sticky session enabled but it might not be working properly and need help in that.

ingress annotations


annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"  # Set the session cookie name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800" # 48 hrs.
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"


frontend connection code

this.socket = io(base_url, {
        // httpCompression: false,
        auth: {
            token: token
        },
        withCredentials: true
       // transports: ['websocket'],
    });


socket server side code(also, im using postgres adapter to broadcast events)

// websocket server config
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  // httpCompression: false,
  transports: ["polling", "websocket"],
  cors: {
    origin: originList,
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});


any insight is greatly appreciated.
Tried the websocket transport too, but it switch to polling even after i enforce it(hope I did it correctly)
